# How to write this query with Laravel ORM

Tags: laravel

I am trying to write this query with laravel orm to use the eager loading but not getting it.

```
SELECT p.* FROM tbl_posts as p,tbl_posts_requests as pr WHERE p.post_status='active' AND (p.post_id=pr.request_post_id OR p.post_private='no' )
```

I have a comment table to eager load with it but i am not able to create a laravel ORM version of this query

Comment: It's not clear why you want to use eager loading here. Eager loading happens for Eloquent models with a specific relationship. But the query above does not specify you want to retrieve info from the joined table. You are just retrieving info from p.*.

Comment: @MarkSkayff eager loading is not added here. I will use the eager loading once this is converted in ORM query.

Comment: Nothing particularly complex here. Look into `where` for the `p` bits and `whereHas` for the pr bits. `OR` is handled by `$query->where(function($query) { ... })` nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent ORM eager loading happens for Eloquent models with specific relationships.

So assuming you have a tbl_posts_requests relationship in your Posts model, it could be something like this:

```
Posts::where(['post_status' => 'active', 'post_private'=>'no'])->with('tbl_posts_requests')->get();
```

I am assuming you called your relationship function `tbl_posts_requests` there.

Comment: i don;t want to eager load the posts requests/

Comment: Pass the arguments properly inside where function